# SpriteKit circle particle effect

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, effects, particles

In iOS SpriteKit. I am trying to create a sk particle emitter where the particle effect will be a circle with some radius r. Any ideas how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The way I achieved this is by using the Color Ramp, starting with a color with zero opacity, to a color with 1% opacity near the end of the range and then having a third color with 100% opacity for the actual circle.

Here are the parameters I used:
Particles: 800, maximum:0
Lifetime: 1.1, range 0.2 (play with that and the location of the colors on the color ramp to set the radius)
position range: x=5, y=5 (not a must)
speed: 30 (should be around that value)
acceleration: x=10, y=10 (small values are good here)
alpha: start=0.3, range=1, speed: 0.1 (play with these)

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be :

1. the particles of a SKEmitter have a position
2. all we have to do is to find where and how to change that position
3. where : in : override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)
4. how : by : The parametric equation for a circle :

   xx = cx + r * cos(a)

   yy = cy + r * sin(a)
5. cx and cy = origin of the circle
6. r = radius
7. a: Int = angle : this variable must be a general variable in range 0...359 and reset to zero when it goes over 359
8. Do not use a for loop in update function but a = a + 1
9. myEmitter.particlePosition = CGPoint(x: xx, y: yy)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use the Particle Emitter Editor. There are a couple of ways to achieve your goal. One of them is to change the Lifetime Start setting.

You can also set these values in code with the `particleLifetime` and `particleLifetimeRange` commands.

[image]

Comment: Ok,  what you are suggesting with the lifetime will make a circle because the texture is going to be a circle and it's not going to last long so it's going to show as a circle. What I am asking is how can I create an emitter where the particles go around in a circle and have a gap in the center just like a circle. So the particles will go around and create a circle of radius r that is empty inside but you have the particles defining its circumference.